# Convert af::array to QVector

Tags: qt, arrayfire

I am looking for a way to convert a image, which is represented (because I used ArrayFire function loadimage()) as af::array to QVector. Any advice on how can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community! What does the documentation for `QVector` indicate, how can such an object be instantiated?

Comment: It can be initialized: 
QVector(int size)
QVector(int size, const T &value)
QVector(const QVector<T> &other)
QVector(QVector<T> &&other)...

But I am not sure how to access elements within the af::array and to insert each to the vector. I am looking for something similar to the 2D array iteration with the 2 for loops and accessing particular element at ij position.

Comment: af::arrays can return a pointer to the memory using the [host](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__method__mat.htm#ga332e06d4340867375a5e415fc1befc1d) member function. You can also write to an array using the same function by passing it in as a parameter. Check out the [getting started](http://arrayfire.org/docs/gettingstarted.htm) guide for simple use cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize QVector from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918772/initialize-qvector-from-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `a` be you `af::array`. Provided you can retrieve the pointer to the actual data via `a.host()` and the number of array elements with `a.bytes()`, the question reduces to "How can I convert a C array to a QVector.

That is already answered here: [Initialize QVector from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918772/initialize-qvector-from-array)